# obtener el nombre del id al hacer click en un div

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

Me preguntaba como hacer que el nombre de un id del div se guarda en una variable y posteriormente mostrar el valor de esta variable con un alert, esto dinamicamente, solo con javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

si entendi bien, lo que quieres hacer es esto:

```js
function showID(clicked_id)
{
    alert(clicked_id);
}
```

```html
<button id="1" onClick="showID(this.id)">Boton 1</button>
<button id="2" onClick="showID(this.id)">Boton 2</button>
<button id="3" onClick="showID(this.id)">Boton 3</button>
```

Comment: Gracias me funciono!